# Action do tipo A é modificado ao clicar Action tipo B

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue código:

**_Layout:**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home", new { @onmouseover = "this.style.color='#5cb85c';", @onmouseout = "this.style.color='';" })</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Sobre", "About", "Home")</li>
     <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contato", "Contact", "Home")</li>
</div>
```

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)


    <a id="voltar_pagina">Outra página</a>
}
```

**JS:**

```
$("#voltar_pagina").click(function () {
    window.location = '/Pagina/Tipo'
});
```

**Problema:**

Quando eu clico `Outra página`(Tipo B), a linha `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>`(Tipo A) perde. Ele modifica a linha para `Tipo/Pagina?Length=9`.

Alguma solução ? Porque não estou enxergando o problema.

**UPDATE:**

Já tentei dessa maneira e o problema continua:

```
<button type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Tipo", "Pagina")'" >Outra página</button>
```

Segue Foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri o problema.

Trocar isso:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home", new { @onmouseover = "this.style.color='#5cb85c';", @onmouseout = "this.style.color='';" })</li>
```

Para:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Início", "Index", "Home")</li>
```